# Need help in finding the root cause for HUNG Threads in java application which runs on WebSphere server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, sybase

Can somebody help me in finding the root cause for below HUNG Thread.?
Please find the stacktrace below.

ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 19" (0000004e) has been active for 765581 milliseconds and may be hung.
There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.

```
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) 
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129) 
    at com.sybase.timedio.RawDbio.reallyRead(RawDbio.java) 
    at com.sybase.timedio.Dbio.doRead(Dbio.java) 
    at com.sybase.timedio.InStreamMgr.readIfOwner(InStreamMgr.java) 
    at com.sybase.timedio.InStreamMgr.doRead(InStreamMgr.java) 
    at com.sybase.tds.TdsProtocolContext.getChunk(TdsProtocolContext.java) 
    at com.sybase.tds.PduInputFormatter.readPacket(PduInputFormatter.java) 
    at com.sybase.tds.PduInputFormatter.read(PduInputFormatter.java) 
    at com.sybase.tds.TdsInputStream.read(TdsInputStream.java) 
    at com.sybase.tds.TdsInputStream.readUnsignedByte(TdsInputStream.java) 
    at com.sybase.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java) 
    at com.sybase.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(ResultGetter.java) 
    at com.sybase.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java) 
    at com.sybase.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(SybStatement.java) 
    at com.sybase.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(SybStatement.java) 
    at com.sybase.jdbc.SybCallableStatement.executeQuery(SybCallableStatement.java) 
    at com.ibm._jsp._prodStatHandlingAgent._jspService(_prodStatHandlingAgent.java:247) 
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) 
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661) 
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:937) 
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500) 
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) 
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121) 
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:239) 
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91) 
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864) 
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583) 
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186) 
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455) 
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384) 
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83) 
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:557) 
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:607) 
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:984) 
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1069) 
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
```

NOTE: Please put a comment if you need further information.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide complete error stack trace

Comment: @DevPa Added full stack trace.

Comment: The above thread is not really hung ... its just reading from a socket ... its normal to see such threads in java core. Can you take a core dump and analyze it using a core dump analyzer https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=2245aa39-fa5c-4475-b891-14c205f7333c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your database (sybase) operations are slow.
In this case you have sent a db query and you just wait for the response.
Generally there are two reasons for this:

1. Your query is not optimized and it takes much time to complete.
2. You just fetch a lot of data with the specific query, so you should narrow the criteria.
3. The DB resources you are accessing are locked by another connection. You may use the DB tools to found out what is happening on your database.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to identify the query which is causing the issue.??

Comment: It seems to be hardcoded in a jsp file (generally this is a bad practice). This makes it difficult to identify the line of code and subsequently the jdbc call you are making. If you cannot reproduce this, i.e. you do not know which jsp it is, you should make a list of which queries are used in your jsp's and analyse each separately.